# skip_before_filter when api_key is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, csrf

I'm trying to build an api for my rails application.

I want to skip the csrf before filter when a valid api_key is present in the non-get requests.

I've tried (I'll validate the api_key once I can get the conditional filter working)

```
(skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token) if params[:api_key].present?
```

But that doesn't work ...

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do your API controllers inherit from ApplicationController?

Comment: I was trying to prevent myself from having to create two sets of controllers to do effectively the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i don't think that can work, because if expression is evaluated during creation of controller class, so `params[:api_key].present?` is false at that moment... u can try

`skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :if =>lambda{ params[:api_key].present?}`

Comment: This seems really promising, but it doesn't work. `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` works without the conditional which is weird.

Comment: ihave checked skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :if =>lambda{ params[:api_key].present?} and it seems to work if inserted after protect_from_forgery

Comment: let me try that. I put it before the `protect_from_forgery` before.

Comment: I can confirm this solution works.  Thank you.  Of course one needs to confirm the API Key validity, either here or somewhere before the request is processed.

Comment: Rails 2.0 syntax: `:if ->{ params...`

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3.2.13 -

None of the above solutions worked (maybe I was doing something wrong?) but this did:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :if => :check_auth
def check_auth
  request.headers["authentication_token"] == ENV['AUTH_KEY']
end
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to make skip_before_filter conditional. You can't use 'if' on a skip_before_filter.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :except => [], if params[:api_key].present?
```